# Exercise about an estimate for the growth of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:(0,x_0]\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that:

1. $f(x_0)<+\infty$,
2. $\liminf_{x\to0^+} f(x)\le \epsilon$ with $\epsilon\in(0,1)$,
3. $f$ strictly increasing on $(0,x_0]$,
4. $f(\frac{x}{2})\le \gamma f(x)$ for all $x\in(0,x_0]$ with $\gamma\in(0,1)$.

I want to conclude that there exist $C>0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)\le C(\frac{x}{x_0})^\alpha f(x_0)$. It should be true but I am not sure how to get it.

Moreover: can I conclude the same if we assume the new condition

4. $f(\frac{x}{2})\le \gamma f(x) + x^2$ for all $x\in(0,x_0]$ with $\gamma\in(0,1)$

instead of the previous "condition 4" ?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but your first question is not difficult if you allow a constant C in the formula.

Assume $x'\in(x_0/2,x_0]$, for any x in set $\{x_n:x_n=x'/2^n\}$

We have $$f(x)\leq(x/x')^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}f(x')=(x/x_0)^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}\cdot(x_0/x')^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}f(x')\leq\frac{1}{\gamma}(x/x_0)^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}f(x_0)$$

Pick C as $\frac{1}{\gamma}$, $\alpha$ as $log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}$, since there is no $x'$ in the last formula, we have your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you! I just have two comments.. First, I didn't understand how you prove the inequality for $x\in[x_0/2,x_0]$ (not a real problem, one can think to give the proof on an interval smaller than the given one). Second, we needed $\alpha<1$, so I think that in your proof we must assume $1/\gamma <2$ (which in my specific case it is not a problem, I think I can arrange this to be true).

Comment: Well, sorry to confuse you in severals details. For the first problem, as you can see, $\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot(x/x_0)^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}\geq\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot(1/2)^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}=1$, so we have $f(x)\leq\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot(x/x_0)^{log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}}f(x_0)$.

Comment: For the second one, it won't be a problem if $1/\gamma\geq2$. Since $x/x_0$ is smaller than 1, $(x/x_0)^\alpha$ is strictly decreasing  on $\alpha$, so you can alter the $log_2\frac{1}{\gamma}$ smaller arbitrarily to keep the inequity right.

Comment: Thank you, you're right!